# How to redirect on button click using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using a button on my form. I am trying to redirect to another page on button click after successful submission of user info. Every thing works properly except redirection. Here is the code I tried.

Html code:

```html
<form role="form" id="contact-form" method="get">
  <div class="form-group row">
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" />
      <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter your address" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-t-primary">Show Me Now!</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript  code:

```js
function contact() {
  $("#contact-us-form").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  form = $(this);
  data = $(this).serialize();
  $.post("contact.php", data, function(response){
      form.trigger('reset');
  });
}
```

Php code:

```
<?php 
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address= $_POST['address'];
    $subject = "Message from: ".$email;
    $content = "Email: " . $email."\n"
            . "Address: " . $address;
    $headers ='Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
    mail('example@gmail.com', $subject ,$content, $headers );
    header("Location:https://www.example.com");
    echo 1;
}else {
    echo 0;
}
```

?>

Comment: This example code has nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: What's really the problem ! What happens when you submit the form ?

Comment: Don't echo anything after issuing a redirect header. In fact, the only thing after it should be an immediate `exit;` to prevent any further code from executing.

Comment: When I click the button, It's send the info at email but not redirecting to any where.

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, but if this would ever be production code, please properly check your user inputs to prevent a mail header injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect an ajax request from PHP, instead use this:

```
$(function() {

    $("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        form = $(this);
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post("contact.php", data, function(response) {
            form.trigger('reset');
            //Redirection
            window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
        });
    });

});
```

Just remove this `header("Location:https://www.example.com");` from your PHP.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Is there any way to do this using php?

Comment: @WaseemBarcha yes, you can but you have to send data using the classic way (without ajax), `header(...)` will redirect the page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to write the entire url when you are setting the header:

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the absolute address, including the protocol (`https://`) in your header location if you want to redirect to a new site.

```
header("Location: https://www.google.com")
```

Without the protocol, the location is assumed to be relative and will be appended to the existing domain.

Additionally, you should not echo anything after the headers.

Comment: I think that's what the OP already did ! I'm curious why it's not working !

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the question.

Comment: Yes! but even with `header("Location:www.google.com")` it still redirect to `http://op-domain/www.google.com` !

Comment: Right, because it's missing the protocol like I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I don't think this is the real problem because it's easy to notice that ! Instead, I think there is some sort of output before the `header`, especially from the `mail` function .

Comment: You're making assumptions that aren't in the original question. The OP didn't include the entire protocol, that's the reason the redirection isn't working. The mail command uses a totally different protocol than http.

Comment: Okey see the OP last comment !

Comment: @Soviut Still not redirecting. Basically when I click the button, it's send the info to email correctly, but not redirecting me to anywhere.

Comment: @WaseemBarcha make sure you're not echoing anything after you set your headers.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually necessary.

Inside of the HTML `form` tag, add where you want to post the data to inside of the **action** attribute.

```
<form role="form"  id="contact-form" method="get" action="postpage.php"> <!-- notice the action attribute !-->
```

Comment: In the question they want to redirect to `google.com`, so this won't work in this case since Google isn't going to be page handling the post.

Comment: @Soviut They want to redirect to Google once they have mailed something to someone on the next page. They don't want Google as such to handle the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
echo '<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=0;url=./yourDestination.php>';
```

As we can see in the code, the page would refresh to the url you declared.

"Content = 0" means that it'll refresh after 0 seconds
You could modify the number if you want!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you have set form method="get", but used $_POST variable under php code. Here's another version using POST method, try if it helps.

```
<?php
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address= $_POST['address'];
    $subject = "Message from: ".$email;
    $content = "Email: " . $email."\n"
            . "Address: " . $address;
    $headers ='Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
    mail('example@gmail.com', $subject ,$content, $headers );
    header("location: https://google.com");
    exit;
}
?>

<form role="form" id="contact-form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group row">
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" />
      <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter your address" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-t-primary">Show Me Now!</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It is still possible that blank email is sent (as no $_POST variables are set). You could actually check your inbox to verify this. BTW, is example@gmail.com your real email address? :)

Comment: Oh just noticed that you have also used Javascript to post the form, so it is setting the POST vars. In my example however, I have placed both the form and php code into a single file so no Javascript is needed for submission of the form. Please adapt the one that best works for you.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to write PHP code that handles Ajax Request:

```
if (isset($_POST['ajax_request'])) {
    // write code;
    echo "http://www.example.com"; // redirect url
}
```

Javascript:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.post('/path/to/file.php', {"ajax_request": true}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        window.location.href = data; // http://www.example.com
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.